# How do I filter numbers which end in other numbers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, filter

For instance, I want to extract from a list the numbers that end in 67: 1637767, 9967, 523467...

Answer (score 3):

Compare them modulo 100:

```
let result = filter ((== 67) . (`mod` 100)) numbers
```

Comment: ``(`mod` 100)``

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work if all you want is to match a `2-digit` number. Here is a more generalized solution:

```
import Data.List (isSuffixOf)

extractSuff :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
extractSuff n xs = filter (\x -> isSuffixOf (show n) (show x)) xs
```

**EDIT:**

Upon Guvante's suggestion, I'm adding another solution which doesn't stringify numbers.

```
extractSuff' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
extractSuff' n xs = filter (\x -> n == (x `mod` (10 ^ (numDigits n)))) xs
    where numDigits n
            | abs n < 10 = 1
            | otherwise  = 1 + numDigits (n `div` 10)
```

Comment: I would recommend against this, you are assuming that the number provided has no leading zeros (since `Int` cannot store `067` it can only store `67`) and you are stringifying which hurts performance.

Comment: @Guvante, I updated my answer to add a solution which doesn't stringify numbers. I don't understand your first statement about leading zeros, though. Could you explain it further?

Comment: If I want to filter `[1037, 137, 2037]` to `[1037, 2037]` how would I do that using `extractSuff'`? Note that if you never need leading zeros that isn't a problem, but if you do it does make this more complex. (Note that doing what I mention requires deciding how to handle `37` in the above example).

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I guess that is only possible through strings since integers, as you mentioned, can't store the leading zeroes.